# Инициатор премии или инициатор создания премии – как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Возможен ли вариант "инициатор премии" или это ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что нет. Специально поискал словосочетания с данным словом и нашёл следующую закономерность:

1. Данное слово очень часто употребляется с отглагольными существительными, обозначающими действие. Например:

**Он был инициатором *создания* премии.**

Здесь "создание" обозначает процесс совершения действия (**не путать со словом "создание", сходным со словом "существо"**).

2. Также употребление возможно при названиях каких-либо проектов, где слово "инициатор" приобретает больше значение должности:

**Он инициатор проекта.**

У проекта есть создатель, заместитель создателя, **инициатор** и т.д.

Поэтому, как я считаю, вариант "инициатор премии" неуместен.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, вариант "инициатор премии" *возможен*, но с дополнительной смысловой нагрузкой: на премию выделяются *собственные* материальные средства. В общем же случае "инициаторы" выступают как учредители премии и ограничиваются организацией сбора средств и установлением порядка её выдачи (это инициаторы *действий* по учреждению премии, но не "инициаторы премии"). Пример употребления выражения "инициатор премии" в отношении частной Нобелевской премии (https://offshoreview.eu/2018/12/14/kto-poluchil-nobelevskuyu-premiyu-2018-kakie-oblasti-nauki-ostalis-bez-vnimaniya/ ):

> Часть денег все же компенсирует Шведский банк, поскольку именно это
>   финансовое учреждение стало *инициатором премии* по экономике.

Comment: Мне кажется, что эстонский частный ресурс - далеко не авторитетный источник в области норм русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "инициатор премии" является калькой с анлийского "prize initiator", "award initiator". В русском нет такого устоявшегося значения у слова "инициатор", но выражение все же иногда используют, поскольку другие определения не лучше (создатель премии? автор премии? основатель премии?). Если нужно придать более литературный характер, то, конечно, лучше "инициатор создания премии".